# When is it OK to assume something like $a \ge b \ge c$ when proving inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Is it okay when the inequality is *cyclic* instead of *symmetric*? For example, to prove the inequality $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ (for positive real numbers $a, b, c$), can I say that WLOG, $a \ge b \ge c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six possible orderings for $a,b,c$ : $a<b<c,a<c<b,\ldots,c<b<a$. (as you see each ordering corresponds to a permutation of $a,b,c$). The cyclic group $a->b->c$ acts on this set of orderings.

For each orbit under this action you can select a "distinguished representative" (the one you like best) and assume that the ordering is distinguished. In the cyclic situation, there are two orbits, so you get two cases instead of one.

Comment: Then what about cyclic inequalities with four variable? How many cases are there?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie In general, for $n$ variables there are $(n-1)!$ cases (the cases may be described as follows: you can assume WLOG that $a_{\sigma(1)}<\ldots <a_{\sigma(n-1)}<a_n$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $[1...(n-1)]$). So for $n=4$ this makes $3!=6$ cases.

Comment: Are there any effective ways to determine whether an inequality is symmetric? For instance, $\sum_{cyc} \frac a{b + c}$ seems to be symmetric but $\sum_{cyc} \frac a{b(b + c)}$ doesn't seem to be symmetric. Am I correct?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie You are correct indeed : $S=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(b+c)}$ is not symmetric because $S=\frac{a}{b(b+c)}+\frac{b}{c(c+a)}+\frac{c}{a(a+b)}$, and if you interchange $b$ and $c$ in the first term, you obtain $\frac{a}{c(c+b)}$ which does not appear in $S$.

Answer (score 2):

A symmetric expression $f(a, b, c)$ means $f(a, b, c)= f(a', b', c')$ for any permutation $(a', b', c')$ of $(a, b, c)$.  Given any three real numbers, we may find a permutation that is non-decreasing, (or non-decreasing), hence we may WLOG assume $a \ge b \ge c$.

But $f(a, b, c)$ is cyclic means this works only for *cyclic* permutations - more precisely we have only $f(a, b, c) = f(b, c, a) = f(c, a, b)$.  There is no assurance one of the cyclic permutations will be non-increasing, so we cannot in general make the assumption $a \ge b \ge c$.

In cyclic case we can always arrange for the first variable to be the largest (or the smallest), so in this case we may assume WLOG $a = \max(a, b, c)$ for e.g.  Or equivalently we may break it into two cases $a \ge b \ge c$ or $a \ge c \ge b$ and prove for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot. For example, consider the cyclic inequality $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \ge ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$$ Is true for $a \ge b \ge c$, but not true for $a \ge c \ge b$. Thus, we can only assume $a \ge b \ge c$ for symmetric inequalities.

However, we can also assume inequalities such as $a \ge b \ge c$ or $a \ge c \ge b$. If it is true for both these expressions, than it is true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Only when the inequality is symmetric with respect to $a,b,c$. In this case, the inequality is only cyclic, so you can assume things like $\max (a,b,c) = a$ or $\min (a,b,c) = c$.